# AWS Redis (v 3.2.6): HMSET is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis

I'm getting the following error when I try to run HMSET. 
I'm not sure what the message means?

```
No way to dispatch this command to Redis Cluster. Missing key.
HMSET ABC12340112163928690398 XYZ12340112163928690429 b'eyJuY2lfaWQiOiAi='
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field's value is not passed properly - remove the leading "b" (a Pythonic value?) and it should work, i.e.:

```
HMSET ABC12340112163928690398 XYZ12340112163928690429 'eyJuY2lfaWQiOiAi='
```